# Getting pattern matched from match object

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

I'm working with Python regex and I'm trying to get pattern matched from a match object not text matched itself.

I have some patterns to replace and I'm doing this:

```py
import re

patterns = {
    r'^[ |\n]+': '',
    r'[ |\n]+$': '',
    r'[ |\n]+': ' '
}

text = ' Hello there,  I\n need your help  here    plase :) '
text = re.sub('|'.join(patterns.keys()),
              lambda match: patterns[ match.group(0) ],
              text)
```

But this is a wrong solution because `match.group(0)` returns text matched so none of them will be equals to any key of patterns dict.

I tried `match.pattern` but get an exception and tried `match.re` but this gives all `re.compile` object and its pattern for this problem is `'^[ |\n]+|[ |\n]+$|[ |\n]+'`.

**EDIT:** based on Barmar solution I got this:

```py
import re

patterns = [
    (r'^[ |\n]+', ''),
    (r'[ |\n]+$', ''),
    (r'[ |\n]+', ' ')
]

def getreplacement(match):
    for i, group in enumerate(match.groups()):
        if group:
            return patterns[ i ][ 1 ]

text = ' Hello there,  I\n need your help  here    plase :) '
text = re.sub('|'.join('(' + p[ 0 ] + ')' for p in patterns), getreplacement, text)
print(text)
```

But still not a way to always get pattern from a match group.

Comment: The pattern matched would be the entire regex expression involving the alternation.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga What he wants to know is which alternative matched.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Basically I need for a match object group wich pattern matched it

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to find out directly which alternative matched.

Use a list instead of a dictionary, and put each pattern in a capture group. Then you can see which capture group matched, and use that as the index to get the corresponding replacement.

Note that this won't work if there are any capture groups in the patterns. If groups are needed, make sure they're non-capturing.

```
import re

patterns = [
    (r'^[ |\n]+', ''),
    (r'[ |\n]+$', ''),
    (r'[ |\n]+', ' ')
]

def getreplacement(match):
    for i in range(1, match.groups):
        if match.group(i):
            return patterns[i-1][1]

text = ' Hello there,  I\n need your help  here    plase :) '
text = re.sub('|'.join('(' + p[0] + ')' for p in patterns), getreplacement, text)
```

Comment: It seems to work, but I did some changes. Also I wonder if there's any built-in solution, better if it's `O(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, you want to strip leading and trailing spaces and reduce the ones in the middle to just one.

First, you code likely has a bug: `[ |\n]` will match a space ( ), a pipe (`|`), or a new line. You probably don't want to match a pipe, but you might want to match all whitespace characters, like tabs (`\t`), for example.

Second, styling: keep your lines under 80 chars and no spaces around indices in brackets.

Third, removing the leading and trailing spaces is simply done with [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip). The only thing remaining to replace now is sequences of two or more whitespaces, which is easily matched with `\s{2,}` (`\s` = "whitespace", `{2,}` = "two or more").

Here is a modification of your code:

```py
import re


patterns = [
    (r"^[ |\n]+", ""),
    (r"[ |\n]+$", ""),
    (r"[ |\n]+", " "),
]


def get_replacement(m: re.Match) -> str:
    return next(
        patterns[i][1]
        for i, group in enumerate(m.groups())
        if group is not None
    )


text = (
    "\n"
    " \t   Hello there,  I\n need your help  here    plase :) \t  \n"
    " \t   Hello there,  I\n need your help  here    plase :)  \t "
    "\n"
)
result1 = re.sub(
    "|".join(f"({p})" for p, _ in patterns),
    get_replacement,
    text,
)
result2 = re.sub(r"[ \n]{2,}", " ", text.strip())
result3 = re.sub(r"\s{2,}", " ", text.strip())
print(repr(result1))
print(repr(result2))
print(repr(result3))
```